# codernitydb string key whats wrong with this code?

Tags: python, codernity, nosql

from CodernityDB.database import Database
from CodernityDB.hash_index import HashIndex

class WithXIndex(HashIndex):

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    kwargs['key_format'] = '16s'
    super(WithXIndex, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

def make_key_value(self, data):
    username = data['username']
        # if not isinstance(login, basestring):
        #     login = str(login)
    return md5(username).digest(), None

def make_key(self, key):
    return md5(key).digest()
```

def main():
    db = Database('l1.db')

```
if db.exists():
    db.open()

else:
    db.create()

    x_ind = WithXIndex(db.path, 'username')
    db.add_index(x_ind)

    db.insert(dict( username='lamar', age='33', frm='new jersey'))

for dt in  db.all('username',with_doc=True):
    print dt
print db.get('username', 'lamar') # throws an exception
```